# Optional Fields in InfoPath; Getting the XML node with VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, vsto, infopath

I use VB to get data through my form. I have some optional fields in my form and I have a problem with the following code:

```
MsgBox(myXPathNavigator.SelectSingleNode( _
  "/my:Status/my:Questions/my:Questions1", Me.NamespaceManager _
).IsNode.ToString)
```

When the optional field `'Questions1'` is inserted into the form I get the value `'true'` by the `IsNode()` function.

If the field it is not inserted I have an exception stating that the reference is not correct (and it is indeed true). Is there a way to verify about a node, whether it is present or not in my form?

Thanks in advance, Sun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do it in one step. `SelectSingleNode()` returns `Nothing` if the XPath was not found. You must catch that condition separately.

```
Dim q As XPathNavigator
Dim path as String

path = "/my:Status/my:Questions/my:Questions1"
q = myXPathNavigator.SelectSingleNode(path, Me.NamespaceManager)

If Not q Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox(q.ToString)
End If
```

Comment: The problem persists. The issue is in SelectSingleNode and note in MdgBox.

Comment: @Sunscreen: What is the exact exception you get?

Comment: A pop-up msg appears when the tag is no tpresent in my form. Explicitely says:

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference is not set to an instance of an object

How can I catch it instead of appearing as a pop-up?

Thanks

Comment: @Sunscreen: Go through your program step by step with the debugger. On which line does the problem occur, exactly?

Comment: Ok, I was getting the value all the time thats wht the esception was appearing. Now, with your code though it never gets tha node, whether it is inserted or not q is 'nothing'. (Set is not valid statement so i just tried 'q = myXPath...)

Comment: @Sunscreen: You were talking about VBA in your question title and tags, but obviously you are using VB.NET. These two are *very* different animals. So… yes, there is no `Set` statement in VB.NET. I'll remove the VBA references.